# How to find a journal for publishing my method without applying it to specific real data?

Tags: publications, publishability

I have developed different algorithms as PhD studies. My algorithms work fine and have some limitation as with any algorithm. My work basically is developing models that help other people in their area. While, my work is very useful for many areas, especially finance and health, I had no specific real data (e.g., finance, health, etc.) to work with. Therefore I worked with general real data sets. For each model, I used several data sets.

My study was on my behalf (so there is no third-party funded project). My supervisors were very happy with my works.
Now, after I have been awarded my PhD. degree (as a monograph), I am really upset to not have published my works.

I tried to publish but all journals I submitted to rejected my papers as I do not use challenging data that they are interested in.
How can I find a suitable journal to publish my work? 
Are there journals that are not interested in a specific area of real data?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Since your two questions (“How to find an application?” and “How to find a journal?”) are very different, I took the liberty to remove one of them. Feel free to ask it separately. In order to get more helpful answers to either question, please clarify: 1) Do you wish to publish only for the sake of sharing your work or do you aspire an academic career? 2) What is the difference between “specific” and “generic real data sets”? —  Note that you can [edit] your question.

Comment: To clarify: Did the _editors_ desk-reject your papers because you didn't use data appropriate _to their journals_, or did the _reviewers_ recommend rejection because you didn't use data appropriate _to your intended application_?  You can address the former by submitting to different journals, but satisfying reviewers _may_ require you to bite the bullet and run experiments with better data.

Comment: @JeffE Yes, they rejected my paper because the data is not appropriate to their journals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that Elsevier publishes MethodsX or journals that focus solely on “Materials and Methods.” Perhaps those may be a better fit.

I don’t see why a typical journal wouldn’t consider that just because of the data set. If thats the case, I would put more emphasis on the model’s strengths and implications in the field.